# A set which only exists in the $\sigma$-algebra completion

Tags: measure-theory

Say I have a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ and its completion $\mathcal{F}^{\ast}$. If a set $E\in \mathcal{F}^{\ast}$ but $E\notin \mathcal{F}$, does that mean that I definitely have sets $A,B\in\mathcal{F}$ s.t. $A\subset E\subset B$ and $\mu\left(B\backslash A\right)=0$?

That is how we defined the $\sigma$-algebra completion in class to prove its existence, but I'm not sure that this guarantees the existence of such sets $A,B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can show that the family consisting of sets of the form $f\setminus t$, where $f$ is any element $\mathcal{F}$ and $t$ is any subset of any null element of $\mathcal{F}$, is already a $\sigma$-algebra containing every subset of every null algebra of $\mathcal{F}$. Therefore that family must be the completion itself of $\mathcal{F}$.

Now if $E=f\setminus t$, then you can choose $B=f$ and $A=f\setminus T$, where $T$ is a null element of $\mathcal{F}$ such that $t\subset T$.